# how do I use append in a while loop?

Tags: python

I can enter a valid gtin eg(12345670, 13245627) and 2 quantities but don't know why they don't both appear in the list when i use the append function, it just prints the last one.

```
products = {}
fi = open("prod_file.txt","r")
for line in fi:
    l = line.rstrip().split(":")
    products[l[0]] = {"desc" : l[1], "price" : l[2], "stock" : int(l[3]), "reorder" : int(l[4]), "target" : int(l[5])}
fi.close
gtin_valid()

cont=False
while not cont:
    quantity=input("enter qty: ")
    if quantity.isdigit():
        qty=[quantity]
        gtin8=[gtin]
        qty.append(quantity)
        gtin8.append(gtin)
        carryon=input("do you want to continue? ")
        if carryon[0]=="n":
            cont=True
            print(qty,gtin8)
        else:
            gtin_valid()
            quantity=input("enter qty: ")

    else:
        print("Please enter numbers only ")
        gtin_valid()
        quantity=input("enter qty: ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove lines

```
    qty=[quantity]
    gtin8=[gtin]
```

because it overrides list with previous values.

And create empty lists before `while not cont:`

```
qty = []
gtin8 = []

while not cont:
```

Comment: on the second time of asking, it asks for the qty twice, and then prints the second gtin and second qty twice in the list. do you know why?

Comment: it ask twice because you have `input()` inside `if/else` (first question)and before `if` (second question). You have to remove `input()` from `if/else`

Comment: 'Enter GTIN-8 number: 13245627
     GTIN is valid
     enter qty: 7
     do you want to continue? y
     Enter GTIN-8 number: 11111115
     GTIN is valid
     enter qty: 3
     do you want to continue? n
     ['7', '7', '3'] ['13245627', '11111115', '11111115']'